# How can I combine two imgs into a single img when I use the transform property?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to create a dynamic list of projects, where each item is accompanied with an image as it's thumbnail. In that list I'd like to feature a few projects at the top, and I want to add another tilted image that reads "featured" in the corner of the project thumbnail.

The problem is: When I hover over the item, the thumbnail is enlarged using the `transform: scale();` property in CSS. The featured tag however, is enlarged from it's own center instead of following the thumbnail. I would like the two `<img>`s to behave like one single `<img>`, but I don't know how.

```css
.itemCard img:not([src="http://hex4nova.cf/assets/thumb/featured.png"]) {
 -webkit-flex: none;
 flex: none;
 border-radius: 15px;
 margin-right: 1em;
 width: 120px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #696969;
 -webkit-transition: transform 0.2s;
 transition: transform 0.2s;
}
.itemCard img[src="http://hex4nova.cf/assets/thumb/featured.png"] {
 position: absolute;
 left: -20px;
 top: -10px;
 transform: rotate(-15deg);
 -webkit-transition: transform 0.2s;
 transition: transform 0.2s;
}
.itemCard:hover img {
 transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="itemCard"><img src="http://hex4nova.cf/w/icon/2017100801.png" alt="(thumbnail)" width="120px"><img src="http://hex4nova.cf/assets/thumb/featured.png" alt="featured"></div>
```

This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow. Sorry if this is a duplicate, I searched a couple of times and couldn't find anything that answered my question.

Comment: the image is not working, can you replace it with a valid one ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif seems to be working for me. Maybe you need to load the images in browser cache first?